# what if we accidently don't use '()' after calling the method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What if we forget put the parentheses after calling function, like when we have

```
renderContent(){}
```

and we want to call it in a `div`

```
<div>{this.renderContent()}</div>
```

what if we forget write `()`?
it shows no error and shows nothing in the screen
and when we put `()` after calling, it shows if I got a problem like this how can I know where I didn't put `()`
if you need more information please let me know

Comment: `()` indicates a call to the function. Without `()` you've got just a reference to the function, which is not an error.

Comment: "showing nothing on the screen" should be enough to show you that you forgot something. It isn't technically an error, so the code still works as expected.

Comment: There must be a protection in ReactJS, because if you use a function reference and if it is converted to text, either using `+''` or `toString()`, it would show the code of the function

Comment: *"how can i know where i didn't put ()"* - The same way you detect any similar typo or logical error, by testing your code and validating the result.  Either manually or by using automated testing tools.  The absence of `()` is not itself an error, there are plenty of times where you don't want to include those.  JavaScript itself won't know what you were *supposed* to do, only what you did do.  It's up to you to test and validate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that will happen in this specific case is it will print the function's code. So for example if you have a function like

```
renderContent = () => {
   console.log("hi");
   return <p>Hello world</p>;
}
```

Then using it without the parenthesis will just print the contents of the function, whereas using the parenthesis will print the JSX for the `p` tag `<div>{this.renderContent()}</div>`
will return `<p>Hello world</p>`
within the div, whereas without the parenthesis, it will just print

```
() => {
   console.log("hi");
   return <p>Hello world</p>;
}
```

which is the function's contents

Comment: Right. You could also say that `renderContent` is a variable of type `Function`. Just like with any variable, it will simply render its value/contents (in this case the function's definition) if you omit the parentheses. But when you include the parentheses, it becomes an expression that will execute the function and produce the function's return value.

Comment: yeah that's a better way to explain. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 2):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Content extends Component {
    renderContent = () => <h1>Hi</h1>
    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.renderContent()}</div>
        )
    }
}

export default Content;
```

This will show "Hi" in the screen.
But if you've deleted `()` from `this.renderContent()`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Content extends Component {
    renderContent = () => <h1>Hi</h1>
    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.renderContent}</div>
        )
    }
}

export default Content;
```

It's showing nothing on the screen, and you would have an error in the console:
`Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.`
Because it supposed to return the structure of the function (if in vanilla javascript), but this is not allowed in React js